# OL3 : Select Image/Marker to drag drop to another coordinate (Visual Issues OpenLayers 3)

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm testing around with images to show markers on map. Unfortunately I don't understand the concept of selection and drag/drop yet. Here is my example:
http://codepen.io/kaepten/pen/wDhKt

```
    // Create the background layer
var layer = ga.layer.create('ch.swisstopo.pixelkarte-farbe');

// Create a map
var map = new ga.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [layer],
  view: new ol.View2D({
    resolution: 1,
    center: [600000, 200000]
  })
});

// Create a local GeoJson
var myGeoJson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    600000.0000000001,
                    200000.00000000006
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    668900.0000000001,
                    162000.00000000003
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
};

// Define a geojson data source 
var source = new ol.source.GeoJSON();

// Read the local geojson 
var features = source.readFeatures(myGeoJson);

// Create a vector source and assign the GeoJson features to it
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: features
});

// Create a vector layer using the vector source
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
});

// Create a point icon style
var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon(({
    src: '//map.geo.admin.ch/1403704943/img/marker.png',
    offset: [1,1],
  }))
});

// Apply the style to the vector layer
vectorLayer.setStyle(iconStyle);

// Add the vector layer in the map
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);




var featureOverlay = new ol.FeatureOverlay({
  map: map,  
  image: new ol.style.Icon({src: '//map.geo.admin.ch/1403704943/img/marker.png'})
});


var highlight;
var displayFeatureInfo = function(pixel) {

  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
    return feature;
  });


  if (feature !== highlight) {
    if (highlight) {
      featureOverlay.removeFeature(highlight);
    }
    if (feature) {
      featureOverlay.addFeature(feature);
    }
    highlight = feature;
  }

};



$(map.getViewport()).on('mousemove', function(evt) {
  var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
  displayFeatureInfo(pixel);
});



var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
  features: featureOverlay.getFeatures(),
  // the SHIFT key must be pressed to delete vertices, so
  // that new vertices can be drawn at the same position
  // of existing vertices
  deleteCondition: function(event) {
    return ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(event) &&
        ol.events.condition.singleClick(event);
  }
});
map.addInteraction(modify);
```

As you can see... there is a marker (Image), and it is draggable BUT the visual is not what I like to have:

Question:
- why I get this weird blue circle for selection/dragging the Image? How can I change this visual? In fact, I like to hide the blue selection circle completely, there should be only a Image.
- can I get the selection to drag the Image on the whole Image (and not only on the position of the Image)? The marker now is only dragable, if I select the blue marker that apears, but I like to have a drag on the complete Image-area.

Any hint will be very welcome!
Thanks

Comment: What you need is an interaction for dragging features. But unfortunately this interaction does not currently exist. And to my knowledge there's no open issue for that yet in the ol3 GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For styles, you need to set style at your overlay level and in in your modify interaction. See this [demo forked](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPWdjo) from your own.

For selecting according to your icon shape, I don't have an exact answer: you can play with `pixelTolerance` for an intermediate solution.

It's seems there is [a work in progress](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/2947) on adding drag ability that may be better in particular for your icon shape question

Comment: Thanks! It's simple, but it's really helpfull to understand the whole styles things. I'll play with the pixelTolerance.

Comment: Updated answer because a WIP on a drag interaction